# How do give a size to an array initialized with localthread

Tags: c#, arrays, thread-local

I want an array local to a thread and want to use ThreadLocal. But how do I give the size off the array?

This isn't possible:

```
class Foo
{
    ThreadLocal<int[]> bar;
    public Foo()
    {
        bar = new ThreadLocal<int[10]>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor that takes a `Func<T>` "valueFactory" to create it:

```
class Foo
{
    ThreadLocal<int[]> bar;
    public Foo()
    {
        bar = new ThreadLocal<int[]>(() => new int[10]);
    }
}
```

[See the MSDN page for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The generic argument within `ThreadLocal` specifies the type of the return-value of the task to be executed. There´s no need to provide any size on it, simply return an array from it:

```
bar = new ThreadLocal<int[]>(() => new int[10]);
```

This is the same as if you had a normal method that would return an array:

```
int[] DoSomething()
{
    return new[10] { ... };
}
```